# Displaying a Three-dimensional Array of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, struct

I am attempting to create a school class schedule plan, using a 3D array of structs.

```
struct SPS
{
string Class;
string Teacher;
int noStudents;
};

struct SPS array[3][4][5];
```

Conceptual View:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to be able to input into the array at a specific location, for example at `[1][2][2]`.

This is the current code I have, but it do as intended.

```
cout << "Class:" << endl;
cin >> array[1][2][2].Class;
cout << "Teacher:" << endl;
cin >> array[1][2][2].Teacher;
cout << "Number of students:" << endl;
cin >> array[1][2][2].noStudents;
```

I am trying to print the array, and it does not show this in the output:

```
for (int a = 0; a<3; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b<4; b++)
    {
        for (int c= 0; c<5; c++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", array[a][b][c]);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some more information? What happens when you run the above code? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Why do you need help?

Comment: This looks fine are you getting any errors?

Comment: Updated. Thank you. I'm trying to print the array, and the new input does not show.

Comment: try `printf("%d\t", array[a][b][c]).noStudents)` instead of `printf("%d\t", array[a][b][c]);`

Comment: Your `printf()` is printing the `struct` as an `int` (that %d bit). Did you mean to print one of the fields? (Class, Teacher or noStudents) Or are you trying to print all three?

Comment: I'm trying to print/return all three in the struct.

Comment: @MikeS in that case, you'll need to print `array[a][b][c].Class`, `array[a][b][c].Teacher`, and `array[a][b][c].noStudents`. (No students? Doesn't really qualify as a class then, does it?` You can do all that in a single `printf(...)` or not, your call. When you just print `array[a][b][c]`, you'll get the address of that struct - an integer - not any of the data that's contained within it. Also, '%d' won't print strings.

Comment: And multidimensional array syntax is evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just output a whole struct like that. `printf()` isn't magic. How is the compiler supposed to know what format to use?

Just use `cout` and `<<` to output each of the members of the struct:

```
for (int a = 0; a<3; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b<4; b++)
    {
        for (int c= 0; c<5; c++)
        {
            cout << array[a][b][c].Class << ' '
                 << array[a][b][c].Teacher << ' '
                 << array[a][b][c].noStudents << '\n';
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `printf()`. In some cases, it can be a lot more efficient than streamed output. For fun and profit, trace into the stl and see everything that happens when you `<<` into `std::cout`.

Comment: @DavidLively I do agree with you on that point. On the other hand, I don't see why you wouldn't want to use `cout` and `<<`. I can't think of a reason that you would want to output enough stuff to the console for the efficiency to matter instead of writing to a file. Using `<<` on a file is pretty efficient according to my own testing (faster than `fprintf()`). I also find the syntax of `printf()` harder to work with, but that may be just because I don't use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `printf("%d\t", array[a][b][c])` you should just use `cout`, with this you do have to get the the Class, Teacher and noStudents for each position in your array. So it should be something like

```
 cout << array[i][j][k].Class << ' '
      << array[i][j][k].Teacher << ' '
      << array[i][j][k].noStudents << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I find no value with this struct

```
struct SPS
{
  std::string Class;
  std::string Teacher;
  int         noStudents;
};

struct SPS array[3][4][5];
```

It is disabled, passive, and provides no useful code to help the rest of your programming efforts.

C++ easily accommodates enabling each instance to perform unique functions.  Specifically, you should consider implementing the show (and fill) within the class.  These functions enable each instance to perform usefully to the application ... i.e. "show()", "dump()", "saveToFile()", "restoreFromFile()", etc.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


struct SPS
{
private:                  // for encapsulation
   std::string Class;
   std::string Teacher;
   int         noStudents;

public:
   // class instance 'show's itself
   std::string show()
      {
         std::stringstream ss;
         ss << Class << ' ' << Teacher << "     " << noStudents;
         return ss.str();
      }    

   // for this MCVE, a simple replacement for file i/o
   void fill(int a, int b, int c)
      {
         std::string s =
            std::to_string(a)
            + '.' + std::to_string(b)
            + '.' + std::to_string(c);
         Class      = "\n  Class " + s;
         Teacher    = "  Teacher " + s;
         noStudents = c;
      }
    // add saveToFile(), restoreFromFile(), dump()
};

struct SPS array[3][4][5];
```

Note - no single-field get'ers nor set'ers are ever needed ... these are a waste of programmer time.

to finish this MCVE, I provide:

```
class T601_t  // a simple test 
{
public:

   T601_t() = default;
   ~T601_t() = default;

   int exec(int , char**  )
      {
         fill3dArray();

         show3dArray();

         return 0;
      }

private: // methods

   // specific to this MCVE, a quick and dirty fill
   void fill3dArray()
      {
         for (int a = 0; a<3; a++)
         {
            for (int b = 0; b<4; b++)
            {
               for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
               {
                  array[a][b][c].fill(a, b, c);
                  // record -----^^^^ self filling
               }
            }
         }
      }
      // your code would enter the a, b, and c from user prompts? 
      // or perhaps a file read?

   // specific to this MCVE, invoke the show method of 
   //                        each element of the array
   void show3dArray()
      {
         for (int a = 0; a<3; a++)
         {
            for (int b = 0; b<4; b++)
            {
               for (int c= 0; c<5; c++)
               {
                  std::cout << array[a][b][c].show() << '\n';
                  // record ------------------^^^^ self showing
                  // it is trivial for this cout to prefix the show
                  // with a triple for readability or diagnostics
               }
               std::cout << "\n";
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
         }
      }

}; // class T601_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   T601_t  t601;
   return  t601.exec(argc, argv);
}
```